# Match array and return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I am learning JavaScript/jQuery and I need some help.

Basically I have a array, converted from an Excel table below

```
Name    Sun  Mon    Tues    Wed     Thurs   Fri    Sat
John    x   21:00   21:00   21:00   21:00   21:00   x
Smith   x   19:45   19:45   19:45   19:45   19:45   x
Paul    x   19:45   19:45   19:45   19:45   19:45   11:00
```

```js
"Name", "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", 
"John", "x", "21:00", "21:00", "21:00", "21:00", "21:00", "x", 
"Smith", "x", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "x", 
"Paul", "x", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "11:00"
```

What I want:

A function when given a input of "John, Monday" or "John, 27/02/2017", will return "21:00".

Any sample code is highly appreciated, as I am fairly new to this.

Comment: Err... So is your question "How do I convert a date to a day of the week?"

Comment: haha no sorry i will edit the question, i might have added too much, My question is how do i get the value for the input, if i put "John" and the date, the function should return the time from the row associated with the name, John, mon should return 21:00

Comment: How do you know the data starts from 27 feb 2017?  or do you just get the week day and get the value from your array?

Comment: @Jules let me explain, originally i had a excel table which i later just converted to array for my javascript, the data does not have any dates, only days, Monday, Tuesday so on as columns , the timings are fixed aswell, now the user will be entering his name and a random date(27/02/2017) fixed format, the only purpose of date is to convert to day then the function checks his name against  the day and tells the time, Like "John Teague" answers which works, but the table has 100's of rows , so i used a online converter to convert the data in my example, so his method requires manual work too.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier if you restructure your data.

```
const data = {
  John: [
      'x',
      '21:00',
      '21:00',
      '21:00',
      '21:00',
      '21:00',
      'x',
  ],
  Smith: [
    'x',
    '19:45',
     '19:45',
    '19:45',
    '19:45',
    '19:45',
    'x',
  ],
  Paul: [
    'x',
    '19:45',
    '19:45',
    '19:45',
    '19:45',
    '19:45',
    '11:00',
  ],
}
```

The array is for the values for each day, since Date.getDay() return 0..6 based on the day. (0 = Sunday, etc).

In JavaScript objects can be treated as a dictionary and you can access them using `[]` notation.

```
const name = 'John';
const dayIndex = new Date('02/28/2017').getDay();
const result = data[name][dayIndex]; // result = 21:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can convert the data row to array (note I changed the minutes for testing)

```js
var dat = ["Name", "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", 
"John", "x", "21:00", "21:00", "21:00", "21:00", "21:00", "x", 
"Smith", "x", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "x", 
"Paul", "x", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "19:45", "11:00"];

var data = [];

for (var i = 1; i < dat.length / 8; i++) {
  data.push(dat.slice(i * 8, (i + 1) * 8));
}

function getIt(name, date) {
  var el = data.find(function(e) {
    return e[0] == name;
  });

  if (el) {
    console.log(el[date.getDay() + 1]);
  } else {
    console.log("not found");
  }
}

getIt("John", new Date());
```

EDIT: added parsing string to data source array.

Comment: Hey jules, i tried your code but i cant seem to make it work, different errors keep popping up, i will try my best to fix it but, could you take a another look ?, i am using jsfiddle by the way.

Comment: @Cyb3rHac3r, what is the error message?  Can you share your jsfiddle?